# What particles can move in the light-cone coordinates?

Tags: particle-physics, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, relativity

Are only relativistic particles able to move in the light-cone coordinates?
Are non-relativistic particles also able to move in the light-cone coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all particles can move in “light-cone” co-ordinates(better known as Minkowski space-time diagrams). But for particles/objects moving at a very low fraction of the speed of light the benefit of studying their motion with the Minkowski-diagram is very low, like there won’t be much difference if or not we used Special relativity. Hence these particles with low speeds approximately follow Galilean-Relativity(relativity where time and space is absolute) so we characterize them as *non-relativistic* but remember that no particle is **fully** non-relativistic, they are only *approximately* so.

Comment: Typical Minkowski diagrams do not use [light-cone coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-cone_coordinates).